# Sum two results from SQL query

Tags: sql

I just started learning SQL. I filtered the data I have and accordingly two results came out. I want to collect these results, but whatever I do, it throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Sec_id]
      ,[Prc_date]
      ,[Mkt_Price]
      ,[Currency]
      ,[Pricing_factor]
  FROM [EXAMPLE1].[dbo].[market]
  WHERE Currency='INR' OR Currency='AUD';
  
  SELECT  SUM(Mkt_Price)* Pricing_factor as INR FROM market 
  where Currency='INR' and Mkt_Price>100 group by Pricing_factor  ; 

 
 SELECT SUM(Mkt_Price)* Pricing_factor as AUD  FROM market 
  where Currency='AUD' and Mkt_Price>100 group by Pricing_factor  ;

 
  
  SELECT  SUM(Mkt_Price)* Pricing_factor as totalll FROM market 
  where Currency='AUD' or Currency='INR' and Mkt_Price>100 group by Pricing_factor
```

and I got these results:

[image]

How can I collect(SUM) and reflect the resulting data ("INR"," AUD")? (Using SMSS)

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using? That screenshot looks like SSMS (SQL Server Managment Studio) which *suggests* the former.

Comment: ARe you not just after an `IN` here?

Comment: use your last query without group by and use case statement to pull INR in one column and then AUD in another column using the case statement. I would recommend you look at pivot feature so it grows dynamically when more countries are added for example.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here. You say at start you have an error, you do not mention what the error is and at the bottom you show the results. So is it an error or is it the result that is not the way you want? Can you please clarify, also please don't post images. See this post about how to post a SQL question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/460557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Currency, SUM(Mkt_Price * Pricing_factor) AS Total
FROM market
WHERE Currency IN ('AUD', 'INR') AND Mkt_Price > 100
GROUP BY Currency;
```

Be careful with operator precedence:

```
 Currency = 'AUD' OR  Currency = 'INR' AND Mkt_Price  > 100
 Currency = 'AUD' OR (Currency = 'INR' AND Mkt_Price) > 100 -- same thing
```

This is what you really wanted:

```
(Currency = 'AUD' OR Currency = 'INR') AND Mkt_Price  > 100
```

To combine the totals with a grand total you could try a union:

```
SELECT Currency, SUM(Mkt_Price * Pricing_factor) AS Total
FROM market
WHERE Currency IN ('AUD', 'INR') AND Mkt_Price > 100
GROUP BY Currency
UNION ALL
SELECT 'All', SUM(Mkt_Price * Pricing_factor) AS Total
FROM market
WHERE Currency IN ('AUD', 'INR') AND Mkt_Price > 100;
```

One you progress past understanding the basic operations you'll want to check into "grouping sets" and "rollup".